# Ruby interpreter ignors conditions of elsif statements

Tags: ruby

I wroe this method in a class :

```
 def OpCodes
  if @asm[0] == "ADD"
   opcode = "111"
  elsif @asm[0] == "CMP"
   opcode = "110"
  elsif @asm[0] == "SHL"
   opcode = "101"
  elsif @asm[1] == "SHR"
   opcode = "100"
  elsif @asm[1] == "NOT"
   opcode = "011"
  elsif @asm[1] == "XOR"
   opcode = "010"
  elsif @asm[1] == "OR"
   opcode = "001"
  elsif @asm[1] == "AND"
   opcode = "000"
  else
   opcode = "ERROR"
  end
  @opcode = opcode 
  return @opcode
 end
```

And when I run the code, and for example I give it "ADD 1, 3" string, it works and returns "111". But, when I use other commands, it returns "ERROR"

Comment: `"ADD 1, 3"[0]` is `A` and should not be the same as `ADD`. Are you really  give the string `ADD 1, 3` or is there a split and you give an Array? Can you please add your call in your example.

Comment: I am sorry, what ruby interpreter ignores? Maybe you ignore ruby's syntax in a first place?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]". Your code won't run as is, making it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite this to use a simple lookup table:

```
OPCODES = {
  ADD: 0b111,
  CMP: 0b110,
  SHL: 0b101,
  SHR: 0b100,
  NOT: 0b011,
  XOR: 0b010,
  OR: 0b001,
  AND: 0b000
}.freeze

OPCODE_ERROR = "ERROR".freeze

def opcode(instruction)
  OPCODES[instruction.to_sym] or OPCODE_ERROR
end
```

Note it's much better to use native binary numbers than string representations of same, so I'm using the `0bNNN` notation here. `0b001` is 1, `0b010` is 2. You can convert back to a string if you want using `n.to_s(2)` for base-2.

Additionally you should never name methods `CamelCase` style, those are reserved for class and module names. Instead use `underscore_style`.

It looks like you're not parsing your input properly. Try with a regular expression:

```
instruction, a, b = input.scan(/\A(\S+)\s+(\S+),\s*(\S+)/)[0]
```

For something like `"ADD 1,2"` you will get those values broken out into three variables you can use.